# VBScript -How to direct click on screen or click on the specific name button?

Tags: vbscript, imacros

I have created an imacros script to automate a task within a web browser:

```
Set iim1= CreateObject ("imacros")

For m = 1 to 80000

i = iim1.iimInit("-ie", true,1000)

    iret = iim1.iimInit()
    iret = iim1.iimSet("row", m)
    iret = iim1.iimPlay("1",1000)
    iret = iim1.iimExit()
Next
```

I created this code for the particular task, but now i want to add some extra functionality. When a specifically named button is clicked, another click action needs to be performed at some other defined x and y position - how can I achieve this programmatically using imacros?

Comment: Have you tried asking your question on the Iopus forums? http://forum.iopus.com

Comment: If you created the "imacros" COM component, why not just add a method to your component that performs a mouse click that you can call from your VBScript? Use mouse_event() or SendInput() or some other API.